# Advanced scripts for router

Tags: networking, scripting

I have a Netgear DGN2200v2 router. I am trying to make advanced scripts for the router. Specifically, I want to detect people using eMule and Torrent, and then block them from accessing for 5 minutes, then give them access back. Also I would like to add a whitelist of MAC addresses where eMule and Torrent are allowed. (Not really important)

Also of course a way to semi-easily disable the script.

Is there any way to do it? I have no idea where to even start searching, and I have no idea if it's even possible to install custom software on the router.

FAILED ATTEMPT 1: openwrt isn't supported by my router

Answer (score 2):

https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start
supported per line 626

```
ipset create ban hash:net  maxelem 200000 timeout 300
ipset create whitemac hash:mac
ipset add whitemac 00:12:00:34:00:56 (add all macs one at time)
ipset save -f /somewhere/ipset.conf
```

on boot up you need

```
ipset restore -f /somewhere/ipset.conf
```

manually add addresses to block list

```
ipset add ban 1.1.1.1
```

You need iptables and ipset.

```
#mac white list
iptables -A INPUT -m set -j ACCEPT --match-set whitemac src
#add to block list if it matches ports
#I don't know which port emule uses, but you can look them up and
#add them, with commas separation instead of <ports>
iptables -A INPUT -m multiport --dports <ports> -j SET  --add-set ban src --timeout 300
#block traffic in the ban list.
iptables -A INPUT -m set -j DROP  --match-set ban src
```

Comment: You found the wrong router, at line 636 (my router) it says unsupported. Any other way maybe?

Comment: Hello? A little bit of support?

Comment: @AmitGold Couldn't find a compatible firmware for your device.